# Java read text file and search for a line

Tags: java, file

I have the following code, which read thru the files and search for the line that start with subject and print out that line. But I only want to read the first line that contain the 'Subject' but currently it getting all the line that start with 'Subject' how can I configure such that it search for the first 'Subject' and print that one line ?

```
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FilePath"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if (line.startsWith("Subject ")) {
                    System.out.println(line);

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use break; statement,

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FilePath"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if (line.startsWith("Subject ")) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use Regular Expressions to find all the occurrences of desired 
[Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) i.e. something like `"Subject*\n"` in your case.
Check out this very good tutorial on Regex: www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You are not stopping your loop, so it will fetch until last line;

try this

```
 if (line.startsWith("Subject ")) {
   System.out.println(line);
   break; // break the lop on success match
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ArrayList you can save each line start with "Subject" and can traverse all of them you can use it according to your requirements

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FilePath"));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = "";

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (line.startsWith("Subject ")) {
            list.add(line);

        }
    }
    System.out.println(list.get(0);
```

Comment: don think i need to store them and get the first line